# fgetcsv in a table gets extra cell

Tags: php, csv

I've used `fgetcsv` in a table and it works fine except the extra cell at the end.
see http://jobbel.nl/csv.php. How can I fix this?

This is my script:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Tijd</th>
        <th>Temperatuur</th>
    </tr>
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<tr><td>";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be it...

```
                    <?php

                    $file = file('templog.csv');
                    foreach($file as $line){
                        list($datum,$tijd,$temparatuur)=explode(",", $line);
                        echo "<td>$Date";
                        echo "<td>$Time";
                        echo "<td>$Temparature<tr>";
                    }
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're echoing the cells a bit strange.
Change it to just echo the `<td>`'s when you actually need them:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<tr>";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo "<td>" . $data[$c] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

There's an alternative solution, using [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), that's a bit cleaner:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . implode('</td><td>', $data) . "</td></tr>";
}
```